# Azure DocumentDB - ReplaceDocumentCollectionAsync

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

In Azure DocumentDB I get the following error when I'm using ReplaceDocumentCollectionAsync:

> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.NotFoundException: The value '' specified 
>   for query '$resolveFor' is invalid., Windows/10.0.17134
>   documentdb-netcore-sdk/1.8.1    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentServiceRequest

I'm trying to perform IndextTransformation on existing Collection and here's my code:

```
        var collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_configuration.DatabaseName, _configuration.CollectionName);

        _logger.Information("Perform index transformation");
        _logger.Information("Create a collection with indexing policy");

        var collection = new DocumentCollection { Id = _configuration.CollectionName };
        collection.IndexingPolicy.IncludedPaths.Add(new IncludedPath
        {
            Path = "/*",
            Indexes = new Collection<Index> {
                new RangeIndex(DataType.String) { Precision = -1 },
                new RangeIndex(DataType.Number) { Precision = -1 } }
        });

        await _client.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExists(collection, _configuration.DatabaseName);
        _logger.Information("Collection {0} created with index policy \n{1}", collection.Id, collection.IndexingPolicy);

        _logger.Information("Change the collection's indexing policy, and then do a replace operation on the collection");
        collection.IndexingPolicy.IndexingMode = IndexingMode.Consistent;
        await _client.ReplaceDocumentCollectionAsync(collection);

        _logger.Information("Check progress and wait for completion - should be instantaneous since we have only a few documents, but larger collections will take time...");
        await WaitForIndexTransformation(collection);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the Collection from the create method which has all the options populated and manipulate that instead. It looks like this:

```
var collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_configuration.DatabaseName, _configuration.CollectionName);

_logger.Information("Perform index transformation");
_logger.Information("Create a collection with indexing policy");

var collection = new DocumentCollection { Id = _configuration.CollectionName };
collection.IndexingPolicy.IncludedPaths.Add(new IncludedPath
{
    Path = "/*",
    Indexes = new Collection<Index> {
        new RangeIndex(DataType.String) { Precision = -1 },
        new RangeIndex(DataType.Number) { Precision = -1 } }
});

var createdCollection = await _client.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExists(collection, _configuration.DatabaseName);
_logger.Information("Collection {0} created with index policy \n{1}", collection.Id, collection.IndexingPolicy);

_logger.Information("Change the collection's indexing policy, and then do a replace operation on the collection");
createdCollection.IndexingPolicy.IndexingMode = IndexingMode.Consistent;
await _client.ReplaceDocumentCollectionAsync(createdCollection);

_logger.Information("Check progress and wait for completion - should be instantaneous since we have only a few documents, but larger collections will take time...");
await WaitForIndexTransformation(createdCollection);
```